# How to find the range of a line glyph in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I know you can set the x and y ranges for a glyph using x_range and y_range as in [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#setting-ranges). Is there any way to read the current x and y ranges from the glyph? I want to read them so I can set a slider widget that starts and stops at the min and max of the x range.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a callback on the x range and y range objects in js. You find a [working example in the bokeh docs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html). Check out the example: CustomJS for Range Update